# Folder creation with timestamp in python

Tags: python, timestamp, directory

Hi I am a beginner in python and not well versed with file operations.I am writing a python script for logging. Below is my code snippet:

```
infile = open('/home/nitish/profiles/Site_info','r')
lines = infile.readlines()
folder_output =      '/home/nitish/profiles/output/%s'%datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
folder = open(folder_output,"w")
for index in range(len(lines)):
  URL = lines[index]

  cmd = "curl -L " +URL

  curl = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

  file_data = curl.stdout.read()
  print file_data

  filename = '/home/nitish/profiles/output/log-%s.html'%datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
  output = open(filename,"w")
  output.write(file_data)
output.close()
folder.close()
infile.close()
```

I don't know if this is correct. I wish to create a new folder with timestamp everytime the script is run and place all the output from the for loop into the folder with timestamp.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have trailing newlines on all the urls so that would not work, you won't get past `folder = open(folder_output,"w")` as you are trying to create a file not a folder, there is also no need for a subprocess. You can do it all using standard lib functions:

```
from os import mkdir
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now

new_folder = '/home/nitish/profiles/output/{}'.format(now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'))
# actually make the folder
mkdir(new_folder)

# now open the urls file and strip the newlines 
with open('/home/nitish/profiles/Site_info') as f:
    for url in map(str.strip, f):
        # open a new file for each request and write to new folder
        with open("{}/log-{}.html".format(new_folder, now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')), "w") as out:
            out.write(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
```

For python2, use `import urllib` and `urllib.urlopen or better yet use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)